# How to break ITask in Delphi/Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I use the following block:

```pascal
TTask.Run(procedure
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
  begin
    loader.Visible := true;
  end);

  ... SQL SELECT

  TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
  begin
    loader.Visible := false;
  end);
end);
```

In general, everything is OK. The problem occurs when I close the Form 
while executing the SELECT procedure.
When I reopen this Form, the loader is active, but the SQL function no longer performs.

How can I complete all Tasks before closing the forms?

Comment: Look at [`TTask.WaitForAll()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TTask.WaitForAll)

Comment: In case you use FireDAC or similar you also might want to look at [Aynchronous Execution/Cancellation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Asynchronous_Execution_%28FireDAC%29)